# Durandal 2.0 router access

Tags: durandal

I am playing around with the Durandal 2.0 starter kit.  Everything works fine out of the box, but the moment I try to include the '`durandal/plugins/router`' module, the page hangs.  All I want is to get access to the current route and the query strings from my viewmodel.  In Durandal 1.2, I could just access the routeInfo that's passed to the `activate()` function, but now this parameter is always null.  How is this done in 2.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to the router has changed in 2.0 and is now `plugins/router`.
Within main.js you should see a `require.config` block that is responsible for the path mapping.

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'text': '../lib/require/text',
        'durandal':'../lib/durandal/js',
        'plugins' : '../lib/durandal/js/plugins',
        ...
});
```

**Edit**: Answered in google groups https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/jRzCQzU5XIg
by @EisenbergEffect

> Curretly there's no way to get the route info. You can get the parameters though. Your activate function will get called with one argument per parameter.

Comment: The path issue is simple enough, but that still doesn't answer the question: how do I get my current URL and querystrings in the activate function? I'm tempted to use window.location, but I would like to think there's a better way to accomplish this using the framework.

Comment: I ended up using window.location to find the hash.  However, the parameters for the query string will be passed along in the activate function (Thanks Rob Eisenberg for the clarification).